# Whats wrong with my Prime number Checker?

Tags: c++, if-statement, primes

I created a prime number checking program which checks the user entered number prime or not.

It detects non prime numbers easily, but when we type prime numbers, it crashes!

I think I know why, but don't know how to rectify them...

Here's my Program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;



float Asker()
{
    float n;
    cin >> n;
    return n;
}


int Remainder(int n, int x)
{
    int q = n%x;

    if (q == 0)
        return 1;

    else

        Remainder(n, x + 1 > n);
    /* 
    Here is the PROBLEM
    */
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Enter your Number : ";
    float n = Asker();

    int r = Remainder(n, 2);

    if (r == 1)
        cout << "That Ain't Prime!\n";
    else
        cout << "Yep Thats Prime!\n";

    main();

    return 0;
}
```

Suppose, when I enter 7, I know that, it checks upto 6, then it should crash!(due to x + 1 > n condition). I don't know how to return 0 when it fails the else condition...

Comment: why don't you try a iterative solution, its easier and clearer to implement

Comment: I believe your code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your question "*Whats wrong with my Prime number Checker?*" a lot of things are wrong:

- Don't call `main()` in main. That's not how you do recursion
- `int Remainder(int n, int x)` and you call it with a `float` (cast is missing) then with a `bool` : `Remainder(n, x + 1 > n);`
- Your `asker` doesn't need to be a float

---

About the recursion within `main` there is two reason:

- With this config you'll get an endless loop;
- > ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main'

Comment: I accept your other points but why shouldn't I call main() in main?

Answer (score 1):

```
//#include "stdafx.h"   //This is an invalid header.
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;



float Asker()
{
    float n;
    cin >> n;
    return n;
}


int Remainder(int n, int x)
{
    int q = n%x;

    if (q == 0 && n>2 )//'2' have to be excluded.
                   //otherwise 2%2==0 can set
                   //'2' as a non prime which is wrong
        return 1;

    else if(x+1<n)

        Remainder(n, x + 1);
    /*
    Here was the PROBLEM
    Remainder(n, x + 1 > n) 'x + 1 > n ' is an invalid paramrter.
    */
    else
        return 0;
}

    int main()
{
    cout << "Enter your Number : ";
    float n=Asker();
    int r=1;        //It is essential to initialize r to 1

    if(n!=1)        //Have to exclude '1'. Otherwise
                //It will assign '1' as prime which is wrong
        r = Remainder(n, 2);

    if (r == 1 )
        cout << "That Ain't Prime!\n";

    else
        cout << "Yep Thats Prime!\n";
    //main();   //Why are you calling main again?

    return 0;
}
```

1. Your first error was " #include "stdafx.h" ". Where'd you get this header?
2. Then inside int Remainder(int n, int x) function you used recursion and  sent an invalid syntax " Remainder(n, x + 1 > n) ". You can't use syntax like x+1>n in a parameter.
3. After that why are you calling main() inside main function?
   And your algorithm needed some touch which I have added and explained in comment.

But you should know that the shortest way to check a prime number is to check n%x==0 till x<=square_root(n).

Comment: @JebinMatthew is there any problem with the answer i gave?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you don't have to check modulo for all numbers up to `n-1`: it is sufficient to check modulo up to `sqrt(n)`. Second, you should return 0 from the function if the next divisor to check is larger than `sqrt(n)`. Here is the corrected `Remainder` function.

```
int Remainder(int n, int x)
{
    int q = n%x;
    if (q == 0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        if(x+1 > std::sqrt(n)) return 0;
        else return Remainder(n, x + 1);
    }
}
```

Finally, it is better to change the type of `n` in `main` and `Asker` from `float` to `int`, and return type of `Asker` should be `int` too.

This is not an exhausting list of what's wrong with the prime number checker in focus - just a way to fix it quickly. Essentially, such prime number checker shouldn't use recursion - it's more neat to just iterate over all potential divisors from 2 to `sqrt(n)`.